# Mac firewall setting with java

Tags: java

I'm going to add some rules in my firewall with java, I'd like to execute this command with java:

```
String [] cmd = {"sudo ipfw delete 100 "};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But I get this error

> Cannot run program "sudo ipfw delete 100 ": error=2, No such file or directory

Any suggestion?

Comment: The _program_ is not named "sudo ipfw delete 100" but "sudo".

Answer (score 1):

This is common error output for Runtime.exec on *nix platforms. Ensure that both `sudo` and `ipfw` are on your path in your runtime environment.

Alternatively you could specify the full  path locations:

```
String [] cmd = {"/path_to_sudo/sudo", "/path_to_ipfw/ipfw", "delete", "100"};
```

Wrt the password for `sudo`, you could have the password [in your command](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line) although there is a clear security risk with this(!)

One solution is to read the password from your application.

- If using a Swing-based application, you could use [JPasswordField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html)
- If using a Console based application, you could use [Console.readPassword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html#readPassword%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

I would try the full path to ipfw /sbin/ipfw and possibly sudo as well.

One question would be how do you plan to deal with entering the password like this?

Comment: thats the other problem I don't know how should I enter password!

Comment: A little reading material http://www.coderanch.com/t/517209/java/java/provide-password-prompt-through-Java  You also might want to research the sudo commands -A switch on OS X to see if you can use it to pop up a password dialog box. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html